Exported animation with meta-rig has unwanted deforms
Screenshots are the same frame. I've also attached the export settings. Characters are modelled with humanoid meta rigs. Essentially characters receive strange squashing and stretching which can be seen on the head of the character to the right and the eyelids of the character to the left are strange. I receive the same issue regardless of format. The seconds image is taken in Apple's Reality Converter but I get the same issue in Blender when reimporting the USDZ into Blender 4.2.



